# How do I configure Total Commander to automatically change sort order for some folders?

Tags: total-commander

How do I configure Total Commander to automatically change sort order for some folders?

Is this possible by creating a "magic" file in this folder?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is not entirely what you need, but if you keep those folders in a **locked** tab - the sort order of those folders will always be maintained.

I'm not aware of any other method.